# Update Jooq's auto generated classes

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jooq

I am using jOOQ with Mysql (with maven).

I have created a new table in my DB, so how can I update the jOOQ's auto generated classes without regenerating the existing classes?

When I run  `mvn clean compile`, it recreates existing classes also

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ does not support "updating" of generated classes, as it does not maintain "dirty" flags for incremental code generation. So, what you're asking for is (currently) not possible.

Comment: @user1573690: What's the use case for avoiding re-generations? Is it taking too long?

Comment: If you're using maven you can create separate project for jooq classes. Then perform mvn install on it and just include it as dependency in you main project.

Comment: @GrzegorzGajos: That doesn't solve the OP's problem where they want to avoid *some* re-generation

Comment: @LukasEder you're right. However this avoids full regeneration on each compile. Might be helpful if you want to speed up things.